# Cisco Nexus RADIUS authentication privilege issue

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, authentication, radius

I'm trying to set up RADIUS authentication between a Nexus C93180YC and a Microsoft NPS Server.

The RADIUS server is reachable and I'm able to log in and get permission granted, but the network role is not applied to my profile.

This means that, while I am able to log in, **I'm not able to do any kind of priv-15 commands like 'copy run start' or anything which needs write permissions.**

Here is the config on the Nexus side :

```
version 9.3(1) Bios:version 05.38
switchname <hostname>
vdc <vdcname> id 1
  limit-resource vlan minimum 16 maximum 4094
  limit-resource vrf minimum 2 maximum 4096
  limit-resource port-channel minimum 0 maximum 511
  limit-resource u4route-mem minimum 248 maximum 248
  limit-resource u6route-mem minimum 96 maximum 96
  limit-resource m4route-mem minimum 58 maximum 58
  limit-resource m6route-mem minimum 8 maximum 8


no password strength-check
username <username1> password 5 <password1>  role network-admin
username <username2> password 5 <password2>  role network-operator
username <username2> passphrase  lifetime 99999 warntime 14 gracetime 3
username <username3>  password 5 <password3>  role network-admin
username <username3> passphrase  lifetime 99999 warntime 14 gracetime 3

radius-server host <ip> key 7 <key> authentication accounting
aaa group server radius <RADIUSGROUP>
    server <ip>

aaa authentication login default group <RADIUSGROUP>
aaa authentication login console local
aaa accounting default group <RADIUSGROUP>
login on-success log
aaa authentication login error-enable
```

On the NPS side, I have created a RADIUS client with the NEXUS IP, and have set up a condition so that only a member of a certain AD group can log in.
I have added the privilege settings to be sent back as a "Vendor-ID" specific "Cisco-AV-Pair" and "shell:roles=*"network-admin vdc-admin"

[image: NPS roles]

When I check privilege on the Nexus switch, it comes back as "-1".
The roles "network-admin" and "vdc-admin" exist on the Nexus switch.

Can anyone point where this config is going wrong ?

Thanks

Edit : next to no authorization commands are available on that switch :

```
(config)# aaa authorization ?
  ssh-certificate  Configure ssh certificate
  ssh-publickey    Configure ssh publickey
```

Comment: You're missing the *aaa authorization* part.

Comment: I'm assuming that for Nexus switches, there is no need of authorization command line. The authorization level is derived from what the Radius server sends. I saw this written in the Cisco doc for Nexus 9000 : "The ACCEPT or REJECT response is bundled with additional data that is used for EXEC or network authorization. You must first complete RADIUS authentication before using RADIUS authorization."

Comment: Authorization is whatever you have configured. Without setting authorization to look at the RADIUS provided attributes, they do not apply. (this is *the* most common configuration failure.) Try a few debugs and you'll see the failure.

Comment: The thing is - there is no aaa authorization configuration to be done on the switch. I edited my initial post to show it.

Comment: Is this issue got fixed ?I am also facing the same issue. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using freeradius users:

```
test1   Cleartext-Password := "testing123"
        Service-Type = Administrative-User,
        Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=\"network-admin vdc-admin\""

test2   Cleartext-Password := "testing123"
        Service-Type = Administrative-User,
        Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=*\"network-admin vdc-admin\""

test3   Cleartext-Password := "testing123"
        Service-Type = Administrative-User,
        Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=\"*network-admin vdc-admin\""

test4   Cleartext-Password := "testing123"
        Service-Type = Administrative-User,
        Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=\"network-admin\""
```

All four test users can login with the correct roles. Of course, it should be either equals (=) or star (*), not both, but it doesn't appear to matter to nxos 9.3.4.

```
n3k-1# show user-account test1
user:test1
        roles:network-admin vdc-admin

n3k-1# show user-account test2
user:test2
        roles:network-admin vdc-admin

n3k-1# show user-account test3
user:test3
        roles:network-admin vdc-admin

n3k-1# show user-account test4
user:test4
        roles:network-admin
```

Comment: Btw, NAS-Prompt-User and Login-User works as well.

Comment: TAC case was raised for this, and the Nexus switch config isn't at fault. Captures show that NPS Server is NOT sending any attribute, despite NPS configuration being correct as well. For reference, NPS version is 6.3.9600.16384, Nexus version is 9.3(1).